# Increase variation between 2 values

Tags: statistics

How can I calculate the percentual increase variation ?

```
June: $ 2.574.724,83
July: $ 4.041.072,22
```

I want also do the inverse, i.e. if I know the increase variation and July's value, I should know the June value.

**What I did**

I think this formula got me the increase variation. It's that right ?

```
((July - June) / July) * 100 = 36,28
```

How can I get the June value if I pass the July value and the increase variation ?

Comment: What you  have calculated is the decrease (in percent) of July. Which is, in this context, nonsense. To calculate the increase (in percent) you should calculate: ((July - June) / June) * 100%

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general formula is Percentage Increase = [(New value - Original value) / Original value] * 100%
So, New value / (Percentage Increase + 1) = Original value

Comment: With this formula, I got an increase of 56,95%, and this value sounds weird for me. 
56,95 + 1 = 57,95
4041072,22 / 57,95 = 69733,77
Isn't the June's value